# Wordpress header external php file - change title?

Tags: php, wordpress

i have an external php file which i m loading the wordpress header and footer into which works fine but does anyone have any ideas how you can change the page title?

```
/* Short and sweet */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('/home/reboot/public_html/wp-blog-header.php');

// get wordpress header
get_header();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying [`wp_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_title) filter in the file works for me:

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/wp-load.php';

add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wp_title_so_18381106', 10, 3 );

function wp_title_so_18381106( $title, $sep, $seplocation ) {
    return 'Embeded WordPress';
}

// get wordpress header
get_header();
```

See: [What is the constant WP_USE_THEMES for?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/12919/12615) and [What is the correct way to use wordpress functions outside wordpress files?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/47049/12615)

Comment: it did not work, but i remove the wp-blog-header and had just wp-load and worked a treat, thanks very much!!

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'title_you_want',10);
function title_you_want(){
   return "my custom title";
}
```

Comment: try changing priority from 10 to 1 maybe

Answer (score 0):

Just below require add the code like:

```
require '../wp-blog-header.php';
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wp_title_so_18381106', 10, 3 );

function wp_title_so_18381106( $title, $sep, $seplocation ) {
    return 'Embeded WordPress | ';
}
```

And this will work!

**Note:** You'll need to add the separator and space, otherwise the thing will join with your site title.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wp_title_so_18381106', 10, 3 );
```

It did not work for me. I fixed the problem by using the following:

```
<?php 
require '../wp-blog-header.php';

add_filter('pre_get_document_title', 'change_the_title');

function change_the_title() {
    return "The title that I'm looking for";
}

get_header();

echo "Here is the content!";

get_footer();
?>
```