# How to call a filter hook in a PHP external file

Tags: php, wordpress, function, filter, hook

I'm trying to call a `filter` hook in a standalone **PHP** file in Wordpress.

This is the code of the file: **my_external_file.php**:

```
<?php
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../../../../../wp-load.php');

add_filter('init', 'test_function');

function test_function (){
    global $global_text_to_shown;

    $global_text_to_shown = 'Hello World';

}

global $global_text_to_shown;

$quicktags_settings = array( 'buttons' => 'strong,em,link,block,del,ins,img,ul,ol,li,code,spell,close' );

//This work fine, shown editor good.
wp_editor( $global_text_to_show, 'content', array( 'media_buttons' => false, 'tinymce' => true, 'quicktags' => $quicktags_settings ) );

//Load js and work fine the editor - wp_editor function.
wp_footer();

?>
```

The issue is that the filter isn't get executed hence the function doesn't get executed.

How can I execute the filter hook on this external **PHP** file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and main problem `$global_text_to_show` is not `$global_text_to_shown`.

The hook `init` is not a filter, it's an action: `add_action('init', 'test_function');`. See [Actions and Filters are not the same thing](http://ottopress.com/2011/actions-and-filters-are-not-the-same-thing/).

Loading `wp-load.php` this way is... [crappy code](http://crappycode.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/wp-load-php-i-will-find-you/) ;) See [Wordpress header external php file - change title?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18381283/1287812).

The second main problem is ***why*** and ***what for*** do you you need this?
Anyway, `init` will not work, using the filter `the_editor_content` will. Although I don't understand the goal:

```
<?php
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/wp-load.php' );

// Requires PHP 5.3. Create a normal function to use in PHP 5.2.
add_filter( 'the_editor_content', function(){
    return 'Hello World';
});

$quicktags_settings = array( 'buttons' => 'strong,em,link,block,del,ins,img,ul,ol,li,code,spell,close' );

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
    wp_editor( 
        '', 
        'content', 
        array( 
            'media_buttons' => false, 
            'tinymce' => true, 
            'quicktags' => $quicktags_settings 
        ) 
    );
    wp_footer();
?>
</body>
</html>
```