# Including Wordpress Footer in WHMCS

Tags: php, wordpress, smarty, whmcs

I'm trying to include the Wordpress Footer into WHMCS.

How do you do it? Is it possible?

I have tried including the footer.php file but nothings happening.

I know that you can use bridges but it's integration in the wrong way, I want to integrate fully as opposed to pulling whmcs into wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from this [How to call a filter hook in a PHP external file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18512186/1287812)

WordPress running on `http://example.com/wordpress`. And the following `test.php` file located at `http://example.com/test.php`:

```
<?php
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/wordpress/wp-load.php' );
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
    get_footer(); 
    // or wp_footer();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

<sub>*See [*What is the constant WP_USE_THEMES for?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/12919/12615)*</sub>

Comment: I have tried using this but it comments out the php code, I think it's because whmcs uses tpl files, using the smarty template system.

I did change the <?php ?> to {php} {/php} but it just results in a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use the browser generated HTML code directly from the wordpress site inside the WHMCS footer, to make them both look similar. Tried with the wp-load.php, but it did not work for me either!